# Embedded Components and Divisors

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, cohen-macaulay

I'm trying to understand a comment in the introduction to chapter 18 of Eisenbud's *Commutative algebra with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry*:

'*..is the unimxedness theorem which explains, for example, why hyperplane sections of smooth varieties do not have embedded components. **This is the reason we can treat divisors as codimension 1 subvarieties**. It is thus a pillar of algebraic geometry.*'

I don't see the pillar =(

What's wrong with embedded components? Is this comment referring to how Cartier divisors correspond to Weil divisors (In regular schemes)? It seems like all you need for this is the codimension 1 local rings to be DVRs. What's the relation between this and primary decomposition of an ideal $(f)$ having embedded primes?

My question is not coherent but maybe someone can just elaborate the quoted text?

Thanks!

Comment: First, Cartier divisors and Weil divisors are not necessarily the same just by your assumption on codimension one local rings. Try $k[x,y,z]/(x^2-yz)$. There are many reasons why embedded components would lead to trouble, let me give one of them. In an $n$-dimensional variety, a nice duality is obtained by using $n$-forms denoted by $K$. Then, on a Cartier divisor $D$, you can get a duality using $K+D$ restricted to $D$, but if $D$ has embedded components, this will fail- a great pity.

Comment: Ohk, but they coincide if every local ring is regular? As for the comment in question ('This is the reason we can treat divisors as codimension 1 subvarieties'), is it just saying they coincide in some other more general case?